# Links to open apps in iOS

Tags: html, iphone, ios, hyperlink

I want to open apps using a link. So when you tap a link in safari, you open an app.

I had already found these links:

```
Message  --- sms:
Maps --- maps://
App Store --- itms-apps://
iTunes --- itms://
Safari --- http://blanksafari.com/
iBooks --- ibooks://
Videos --- videos://
Music --- music://
Mail --- mailto:
Reminders --- x-apple-reminder://
Calendar --- calshow://
```

I also want to open following apps with a link, so my question is… What is the link to open those apps?

```
Phone
Photos
Camera
Clock
Game Center
Notes
Passbook
Settings
Facetime (app is in iOS 5 and iOS 7)
Weather
Contacts
Calculator
Stocks
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The apps would need to have a custom URL scheme registered in their info.plist. A registry site was launched a while back in an attempt to make it easier for developers to discover existing custom URL schemes: http://handleopenurl.com/
Unfortunately, the site has been blacklisted by Norton Safe Web, so **click at your own risk.**

UPDATE: The site is no longer available. Click on the original link only if you want to fall into the vast emptiness of the web **or** visit the Wayback Machine at Internet Archive to see the site in its glory days.

https://web.archive.org/web/20161128234603/http://handleopenurl.com/

Comment: Eset detects trojan 'JS/TrojanDownloader.FakejQuery.B' with that url.

Comment: Linked website no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

Have to many possibility, here there a calling from Safari from developer.apple.com:

[iPhoneURLScheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Here there a youtube dev for chrome mobile

[Youtube scheme for chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/ios-links)

This Is for Linkedin: `linkedin://profile/{id}`

The best way to get all information is to learn the [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) Scheme, and if you want with phoneGap you can try to convert your web app in to a Partial Native app in Xcode.

Hope this help you.

Comment: PhoneGap link seems to be outdated or otherwise not working.