# UIWebView can't open link

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have word document (.docx) with hyperlink, which points to my own app with specified app URL -> **myApp://url**. There is problem with [`webViewShouldStartLoadingWithRequest:navigationType:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:) delegate event, when I open this document in UIWebView and try to tap on link.

It works, if the link is in full form like -> "File is located myApp://fullURL" in text, but if the link is hidden behind some word like "File is located [here](http://apple.com).", UIWebView doesn't recognize link and event is not fired.

Does anyone have the same problem? Regular hyperlink (http://) works well.

Comment: Please show your codes inside your question ( edit it )

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086672/links-to-open-apps-in-ios

Comment: @Raptor This is simple use case, there is no code to show. Simple word document with hyperlink and UIWebView. Hyperlink is in format "File is located here." (here is the hyperlink to app).

Comment: @pedrouan I don't know what is behind word document hyperlink, I guess it is a href. And yes, when the link is in plain text in full form, it works, the problem is, when hyperlink is behind some word or text, as i described.